# Custom Upload Advanced Scripting CMS

Tags: cms, looking-for-a-script, uploading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I am looking for a specific content management platform that would display themes for my application. Requirements are as folllows:

- Any user can upload content, but has to be approved by an administrator
- When the user uploads the content, an external application is called to generate a thumbnail

I could create this using codeigniter or something, but I would much prefer to use an existing system. I have experience with Drupal (seems a little bloated for my needs), and Wordpress (I'm using it as main website right now).

Maybe I need a plugin for WordPress instead of another CMS. WordPress currently blocks uploads of my file type. I can modify it, but it's a pain to update it every time WordPress has a new release.

Comment: I think I may just build my own wordpress plugin to do what I need. It already has UAC, uploading (though I'll have to add my extension), and I think I can use PHP to call an external Python script, if my host allows it. Other suggestions would still be helpful though.

Comment: I would second your plan to write the plugin, if you haven't already. This will protect you from upgrade issues and may expose you to more options that are already built-in. WP has most of the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[NextGEN Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) for WordPress or maybe some [other galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/gallery)

Comment: I'm looking more for a blog-style display. The image is not the main requirement, it's uploading content that I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of content are you wanting the user to upload?

Have you looked at [PhotoSmash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/) or [User Submitted posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-submitted-posts/), both of these enable user submitted content to vairious degrees, you could also fork one of them to better adapt it to your needs.

Comment: It's a custom theme for a program that I built. It's a zipped file with content. I'm not really looking at doing this anymore. This has been a while ago.